# add and increment array elements by arraycopy

Tags: java

suppose an array of object: Element T[ ] , each object contains two integer variables (x,y).

```
T = (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4)
```

I want to increment the value of the variable **x** of object each time a new element is added to array **with the faster way possible** . The new element can be added in any position and we increment all **x** element after the insertion position (position +1)

Before add (6,6)  :

`T = (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4)`

After add (6,6) in different positions:

1) T = **(6,6)** (*2*,1) (*3*,2) (*4*,3) (*5*,4)

or

2)  T = (1,1) (2,2) **(6,6)** (*4*,3) (*5*,4)

or

3)  T = (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) **(6,6)** (*5*,4)

I used the method **arraycopy** to add the new element, and loop **for** to increment the variable **x** for each element, as follow:

1. increment all `x` of object elements with loop for
2. `Ta[0] = (6,6)`
3. `araycopy(T, 0, Ta, 1, T.size-1 );`

because it is faster than

```
While (i< T.length){

  T[i] = T[i+1]

  T[i].x ++;

   i++;
}
```

I need to add the new element and increment the other objects of array simultaneously with a faster time.

//-------------------

public class elemt {

```
public int x;
public int y;

public elemt(int a, int b){
    this.x= a;
    this.y= b;
}


public void inc(){
 x++;
}

int getX(){
    return x;
}

int getY(){
    return y;
}
```

}

//----------------

public class TAD {

public static ArrayList < elemt >  T = new ArrayList < elemt > ( );

public static ArrayList < elemt > T1 = new ArrayList < elemt > ( );

```
 public static void main(String[] args){



    for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++){
       T1.add(new elemt(i, i));
      }


     long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

      T1.add(0, new elemt(1, 1));

     long t1= System.currentTimeMillis()- t0;

     System.out.println("Time without Incrementation : "+t1);


 //--------------

     for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++){
       T.add(new elemt(i, i));
      }


    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

       T.add(0, new elemt(1, 1));

        for(int i=1; i<T.size(); i++){
          T.get(i).inc();
        }

    long t3= System.currentTimeMillis()- t2;

  System.out.println("Time with Incrementation: "+t3);



 }
```

//------- The results:

Time without Incrementation : 15 ms

Time with Incrementation: 156 ms

My objective is to minimize as possible the time of incrementation process

(Time with Incrementation < Time without Incrementation * 2 )

because actually

Time with Incrementation (156 ms) =  Time without Incrementation (15 ms )* 10

I notes that i can added a new element in any position, but i chose the worst case (adding an element in the first position that requires the incrementation of all **x** element of the arraylist)

Comment: you can use list, there is a method called addFirst() that insert an object to the head of the list.. and than you can iterate the list from the second element and increment the value of variable X

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an array, use a [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), probably a [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). This has `O(1)` insertion at the front time.

```
public void addAndIncrement(Deque<Point> deque, Point new) {
  for(Point p : deque) {
    p.x++;
  }

  deque.addFirst(new);
}
```

Or something.

Comment: Oh boy... `p.x = p.x++` ???????

Comment: we can add an element at any position not only in the first one

Comment: @MMD does order matter?

Comment: the order is very important

Comment: I added the java code to better explain my problem

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you using List (LinkedList for example) if you do the insert often.

It allows you to easily insert an element at any position. also easily iterate over the List to do some work on each element.

In case you want to give 3rd party lib a try, e.g. guava, you could try guava's:

Lists.transform(List, Function)
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List, com.google.common.base.Function)

it does a `map(list, function)` like function. So  you don't have to do the iteration by yourself, just let the `transform` method know, what do you want to do on each element. then It does it for you.

P.S. How to write the markdown http link with label, when the link containing `brackets` ?

Comment: This is a situation where the implementation of the `List` matters, not all lists have `O(1)` insertFront time. For example, `ArrayList` has `O(n)` insertFront.

Comment: yes linkedlist is better for insertion/deletion for sure!. you are right. I don't know how OP want to access the element, also how often the random access will occur. so didn't specify the concrete List implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion (some 'out of the box' thinking):

If you have no other requirement and only access `T` objects via the array, you don't really have to increment the first element of the pair.

When you do this today (that you are incrementing the first value)...

```
given T[i] = (firstElement, secondElement);
x = firstElement;
y = secondElement;
// work with x and y now...
```

...you can do this (and don't ever need to increment the `firstElement`):

```
given T[i] = (firstElement, secondElement);
x = firstElement + i; // add the index!
y = secondElement;
// work with x and y now...
```

This will turn your O(n) complexity of insertion into a O(1). But, of course, this highly depends on your scenario and on how you are using `T` objects' values.